# Can I update from CM 12.1 to CM 13 using OTA, or do I need to follow instructions?

Tags: cyanogenmod, ota-update, nexus-9

I've got a Nexus 9 running Cyanogenmod 12.1. Yesterday I read [Cyanogenmod's announcement of version 13](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cm-13-0-release-1), which contains instructions on how to update to the new version. They write that I have to flash the image, Google Apps and `vendor.img` manually.

However, today I received an update notification on my device:

[image: Update notification]

Can I just apply the OTA update? Or do I still need to follow the instructions (i.e. flash Google Apps and `vendor.img`)?

Comment: You can take a Nandroid backup and try the experiment yourself. If it doesn't work out well, you would know the answer.

Comment: By the way, unless you wipe the **/system** partition completely, the Gapps packages (downloaded from OpenGapps) usually don't get wiped out in the process of updating said partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OTA-update will only update CM itself. You will still have to flash Google Apps and vendor.img manually. If you had Google Apps installed and only do an OTA-update, your Google Apps will most likely be incompatible with your system, causing your device to get stuck in a boot loop.

I don't have a Nexus 9, so I don't know if the old vendor.img is compatible with CM13, but I would recommend to update it as well, just to be sure.